# How to change displayPriority of MKUserLocation annotation in MapView?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a MapView displaying some annotations with `displayPriority = .defaultHight` to allow automatic clustering.

The MapView also displays the current user location which has a default display priority of `required`.

This causes my annotations to be hidden by the user location annotation when they are very close together.

I want to change this behavior by setting the display priority of the user location annotation to `defaultLow`.

I tried using this approach:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        let userView = mapView.view(for: annotation)
        userView?.displayPriority = .defaultLow
        return userView
    }
    return mapView.view(for: annotation)
}
```

However `userView` is always nil and therefore my `displayPriority` modification is not applied.

Any ideas how the `displayPriority` of the `MKUserLocation` annotation view can be changed?

Comment: Did you find an answer/workaround to your problem yet?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to solve this problem by customizing the default user location annotation, but to no avail.

Instead, as a workaround, I made my own location marker and hid the default location annotation. Here's my code:

Add an annotaion variable to your `viewController`:

```swift
private var userLocation: MKPointAnnotation?
```

In your `viewDidLoad`, hide the default location marker:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = false
```

Update the location in `didUpdateLocations`:

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let userLocation = locations.first else { return }
        if self.userLocation == nil {
            let location = MKPointAnnotation()
            location.title = "My Location"
            location.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate
            mapView.addAnnotation(location)
            self.userLocation = location
        } else {
            self.userLocation?.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate
        }
    }
```

Then customize the annotation view in `viewFor annotation`:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            // user location annotation
            let identifier = "userLocation"
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                (annotationView as? MKMarkerAnnotationView)?.markerTintColor = .blue
                annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            } else {
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }
            annotationView?.displayPriority = .defaultLow
            return annotationView
}
```

I changed the annotation's `displayPriority` to `.defaultLow` to make sure it won't hide other annotations.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with this, you can do this using `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView])`:

```
// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
            view.displayPriority = .defaultLow
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can still use the system provided view for `MKUserLocation` without having to construct your own manually.